# Laravel group by array - illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

I already transformed a csv file into the array and grouping the array data with some key. I defined a groupBy function to process the array data. However, I'm facing this error and not sure which part goes wrong.

Code:
groupby function

```
public function group($key, $item) {
        $result = array();

        foreach($item as $val) {
                $result[$val[$key]][] = $val; <--error $key

        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Data transform function.

```
public function saveNewSale()
    { 
        foreach (array_chunk($items, $chunk_size) as $chunk) {
                $cleaned_items = [];

                foreach ($chunk as $item) {
                    //Data Transformation

                    //call groupby function
                    $byGroup = $this->group('ref_num', $item);

                    array_push($cleaned_items, $item);

                }
```

This is my array

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:13 [
    "ref_num" => "INV699"
    "payment_term" => array:2 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Cash"
    ]

    "items" => array:1 [
      0 => array:8 [
        "code" => "3MVR0003"
        "description" => "3M Vinyl 
        "tax_value" => 0.06
        "qty" => 1
        "unit" => 1
        "price" => 10
        "total" => 212
        "total_tax" => 12
      ]
    ]
    "terms" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "date" => "2019-02-20"
        "amount" => 200
      ]
    ]
  ]

  1 => array:13 [
    "ref_num" => "INV699"
    "payment_term" => array:2 [
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Cash"
    ]

    "items" => array:1 [
      0 => array:8 [
        "code" => "sony"
        "description" => "3xperia"
        "tax_value" => 0.06
        "qty" => 1
        "unit" => 1
        "price" => 10
        "total" => 212
        "total_tax" => 12
      ]
    ]
    "terms" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "date" => "2019-02-20"
        "amount" => 200
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I need to group this two array based on `ref_num`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrite your code in `saveNewSale` and remove `group` function

```
public function saveNewSale($items)
{ 
    $groupedArray = [];

    foreach (array_chunk($items, 2) as $chunk) 
    {
        foreach($chunk as $entry) {
            $groupedArray[$entry['ref_num']][]= $entry; 
        }
    }
    return $groupedArray;
}
```

here is working [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e0c535ac5c6869901a17e28d4747ee783aab78c)

Comment: @soyacincau as I understand your code, you use too much foreach loops - in above code I use two - but in your code you use 3 (two in save and one in group) - so it looks like you code go "too deep" into array (and tray read 'ref_num' key from string ref_num)